# When to use globals (or at least file wide) variables in Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

As a JavaScript developer*, I am wired to ***avoid globals*** of any kind, but I can't help but wonder if there are times they are "OK."  For instance, I have a file of utility classes that are used all over my app and they often use "Pretty Print" for debuging.  So should I include:

```
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
```

in almost every func or would it be ok to declare this at the top of the file just below the imports so that all funcs have access to it??

To be frank, I am still learning what "***Pythonic***" means and thoroughly respect that we, as a community, are better off following very similar styles. So, I would appreciate all perspectives.

---

*I am a JavaScript developer who is also frantically and enthusiastically embracing the greatness that is Python!

Comment: Generally one should just try to avoid too many global variables full stop. It isn't about what language you work in, this is just general programming theory. It can be OK for constants etc. but not for general operations.

Comment: It's a general rule that global variables are bad. It's also a general rule that repeating yourself is bad. Sometimes you have to trade off between different rules. In this case, I the DRY violation of putting the exact same line of code in every function massively trumps the no-globals violation of putting something that is a constant but arguably isn't _obviously_ a constant at the global level.

Comment: Also, it might be even more reasonable as a global in some particular module that everything else imports (maybe even with `from myapputils import pp`, which of course makes it a global again, and also violates the "avoid `from…import` if possible" guideline). Then you can change it in one place and affect all of your modules.

Comment: One more thing: have you read [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP 20](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)? They certainly don't answer every question about "what is Pythonic" (including this one), but they give you a good background to start from.

Comment: It seems sensible to treat your `pp` more like a function (indeed you could assign `pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint`) than a "variable" - you wouldn't define the same function inside every other function, and you shouldn't have this same line in every other function.

Comment: Oh wait, one more one more thing… When balancing the tradeoffs, keep in mind that globals in Python aren't _quite_ as bad as they are in JS, both because Python has a module system, and because Python makes it harder to declare "accidental globals". Although I think in this case, even in JS I'd use a global for this.

Comment: @abarnert Isn't the guideline more about `from ... import *` rather than avoiding *any* use of a `from ... import` statement?

Comment: @chepner: `from spam import *` is worse than `from spam import eggs`, and should be avoided _more_. But even the latter can lead to confusion, so it's worth thinking about before doing. (Of course arguably the most confusing way to use it is to define a fallback `eggs`, then `try` to `from spam import eggs` over it, but the benefits of that pattern mean it gets used all over the stdlib, especially in 3.x, anyway…)

Comment: I've never seen how `from spam import eggs` would lead to any more confusion than if you had `def eggs(): ...` at the global scope. If you see a call to `eggs` somewhere in your code, you know it's either due to a `def eggs(): ...` call somewhere, or a `from ... import eggs`.

Comment: In that example, pp is not what I'd call a global variable but more an alias, so it is Pythonic IMO

Comment: @chepner: For the same reason that creating a new `global` inside a function can lead to confusion: because there is no `def eggs` or `eggs =` to find at the top level, so you have to search farther.

Comment: @abarnert I don't see those as the same. For both `from spam import eggs` or `spam.eggs`, you have to go to `spam.py` to see what `eggs` actually is. (I agree that using `global` in a function to create a global variable would be Bad.)

Comment: Unless performance is crucial I would go for `def pretty_print( printer= pprint.PrettyPrinter( indent=4).pprint, *args, **kwargs): return printer(*args, **kwargs)`. But I think it all depends where do you need it done: bunch of scripts? part of a large, multiteam project?

Comment: @chepner: For `spam.eggs` it's obvious at the point of use that you're going to have to look at `spam.py`. For `eggs`, it's not obvious until you scroll back up to the top and find the `from spam import eggs`. (Although really, your example is more a matter of why namespaces are often good in general, than of this in particular.)